# react js not displaying fetched data

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am working with react js and created a simple hook named Test and fetched data from `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` . Data is fetched successfully, but it displays nothing. Not showing any errors. It shows all posts in browser's console because of this line `console.log(res.data)`

```
import React,{useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";


export default function Test(){
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data)
            setPosts(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    },[]);

    
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post=>{
                        <li key={post.id} >{post.title}</li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )}
```

Any help would be appreciated! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, i wasted couple of hours and found error just after posting  the question.
I am trying to display in wrong way. there is issue with using method `map()`.
it should be

```
{
   posts.map(post=>(
     <li key={post.id} >{post.title}</li>
   ))
}
```

instead of

```
  {
       posts.map(post=>{
         <li key={post.id} >{post.title}</li>
       })
    }
```